# Hibernate 3 one to many pagination

Tags: hibernate, pagination, one-to-many

I have an Entity named Question who has a one to many relationship with Answer

```
@Entity
@Table(name="question")
public class Question{
   .....

   @OneToMany
   List<Answer> answers;

   ....
}
```

'Cause there're too many answers for a question, it's not possible to display all the answers one time, however if you select out one question, all the associated answers will be loaded as well, else you have to specify your code to fetch the answer separately, like this:

```
public List<Answer> fetchAnswers(Question q, int onePageRows, int currentPage){
   int limitFrom = onePageRows * (currentPage - 1);
   int limitTo = onePageRows * currentPage;
   String sql = "from Answer where Question_id = ?";
   SQLQuery query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
   query.setInteger(0, q.getId());
   query.setFirstResult(limitFrom);
   query.setMaxResults(limitTo - limitFrom);
   List<Answer> list = query.list();
   return list;
}
```

I think this way will 'break' the one to many relationship between Question and Answers, I won't get any benefit from this relationship in Hibernate3,

What I'm thinking is whether there is a way like this:

```
Question q = questionService.getLastQuestion();
List<Answer> list = q.getAnswers().fetch(startPos, endPos);
```

but, while invoke g.getAnswers() doesn't mean retrieve all the answers into the list then select a range again from the list.

I don't know whether Hibernate 3 supports this or not, if has how to modify, else is there any better way to solve such kind of situation?